# How to create multiple page app with vue-cli(webpack) (with different router for each one, and different dist/index.html)

Tags: node.js, vue-router, vue-cli

- I want to serve different vue pages from server by different routes. For now I'm using only one route (/static) to serve vue files for one "page" that contains vue-router.

  ---
- I can't go one like this because the application should use cookies to verify access rights to different pages.

  ---

## How can I accomplish this without using browser cache ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-Page apps are now supported very well with vue-cli v3:
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#building-a-multi-page-app

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution for me. Unfortunately not a build in one. I just ran build process for two different builds with two different webpack configs which in their turn have different entry and output properties. Just in case someones find this helpful.

Comment: Can you give more details for beginners like me?  How did you get the build process to run for two different webpack configs?